# Parameter is not valid with saveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button which intends to save an Image of a pictureBox I have.

This is the code:

```
private void btnGuardaImatge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp| Png| *.png| Tots els fitxers(*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(saveFileDialog.FileName);
            pctOriginal.Image = b;
            this.imatge = b;
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me this error all the time on the first line inside the `if()` block:

> **System.ArgumentException:** 'Parameter is not valid.'

I tried this instead:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Filename: saveFileDialog.FileName);
```

But no luck... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a conflict between what the code is trying to do, and what you say the code should be trying to do.

On the one hand, we have this:

> button which intends to save an Image of a pictureBox

along with the use of a `SaveFileDialog`.

On the other hand, we have this:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(saveFileDialog.FileName);
pctOriginal.Image = b;
this.imatge = b;
```

Which is opening an existing image from a file and shows it in a PictureBox, rather than saving the PictureBox to a file.

*They are exact opposites.*

If you intend the former, you need to do this:

```
private void btnGuardaImatge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp| Png| *.png| Tots els fitxers(*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pctOriginal.Image.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```

And if you intend the latter, try using an `OpenFileDialog` instead of a `SaveFileDialog`.

Comment: But if I want to save? I don't understand

Comment: Perfect, I understand the mistake I was clearly doing. Thanks, really appreciate your time.